# zend framework 2 in a subdirectory

Tags: zend-framework2, subdirectory

I want to put zend framework 2 in a subfolder.  The skeleton app works out of the box by putting the whole app in a sub-directory and then using domain.com/path/to/public/index.php, but I want to avoid having the long url and I don't want everything else to be in my DocumentRoot other than my public folder.

I thought about having multiple modules, but I have other types of applications under my domain and can't have the public folder be the DocumentRoot nor do I want to recreate everything I have to be a module just to serve a static page.  Ideally, it would be nice to keep the regular directory structure that the skeleton app uses.

I'm using a typical LAMP stack with RHEL and/or CentOS.

Comment: So you want to keep the Skeleton-Structure but a short url, is that all?

Comment: Well basically it doesn't matter WHERE the Files are stored, you only need to configure your Apache to set up your `VirtualHost` to the public directory. Then all you need to do is call `domain.com`. I'm not fond of linux, so i can't give you instructions for that, but to me it seems this is all you're looking for

Comment: I think it can be accomplished with a symlink

Comment: I have other apps in the DocumentRoot and want to add this to it under a subdirectory.

Comment: Other app means other domain, other domain means other VirtualHost?

Comment: I agree that should be the case in a lot of instances, but it's not always possible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the best way, but this is a way that worked for me.

Apache virtualhosts.conf (you could put this in httpd.conf with a few modifications):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps
    ServerName apps.domain.com:80
    ServerAlias www.apps.domain.com
    UserDir Disabled
    ErrorLog logs/domain_error_log
    Options FollowSymLinks

    <Directory /var/www/html/apps/subdirectory/>
            #same stuff in standard zf2 .htaccess file
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
            RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
    </Directory>
```

Location for app:

```
/var/www/zf2_app
```

Symlink:

```
ln -s /var/www/zf2_app/public/ /var/www/html/apps/subdirectory
```

A couple of things to note:  The Directory directive is based off the filesystem path not the URI; it is a one line in the Apache documentation that I forget because if you are using mod_rewrite in the VirtualHost directive it is based off of the URI.  Also, Options FollowSymLinks must be on for the symlink to work and for mod_rewrite to work in a directory directive.

After I reloaded httpd, I was able to browse to my zf2 app using:
apps.domain.com/subdirectory/module

This allowed me to keep the regular zf2 skeleton app structure.  Also, by keeping it together, I can use git (or other source control) to push without having to split things up.

Answer (score 0):

I had added the environment variable in the .htaccess file like this, set the first line of your .htaccess with the ZF2_PATH environment variable (which is at the root of your application folder)

```
SetEnv ZF2_PATH /home/homefolder/zendpath
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
....
...
```

Comment: I think this would work to change the location of the Zend library, but I want to place my whole app in a subdirectory.