# How can I run Zend Framework code alongside legacy (non-ZF) code on the same server on the same HTTP port?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, configuration, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have a large codebase that I am trying to eventually convert to Zend-Framework-powered stack.

I at times write new modules to where I have a choice:

- keep writing using legacy routing/initialization/etc
- somehow figure out how to use ZF for the new module only while the rest of the legacy code works "as before"

Is this possible?
How?

To give you an idea, code I have now uses proprietary multiple routing files, where everything in ZF goes through one single router file.

So legacy code is called like so i.e.:

```
http://legacy:80/index.php?route=product
```

May be similar to [zend framework 2 in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403071/zend-framework-2-in-a-subdirectory)

**Zend Middleware approach**

I was able to follow https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mvc/middleware/ and implement an `IndexMiddleware` class.  I can see that `IndexMiddleware::process()` method is being called.  But I am not certain how to go further, and how to engage my legacy web application to return data as before.
MiddlewareListener.

**Legacy App - index.php**

```
$module = filter($_GET['p']);
if (!empty($module))
   $inc = 'portal/{$module}.php'; //prep a legacy module
require($inc);  //run module
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions there... Depends on how much new code you have, and addresses you want.

Long story short, you could work at the server level (`aliases`, `rewrite`, etc), or at the PHP code level.

Something you could do is use the index.php from the Zend Skeleton for instance, and the default url routing through `index.php`. Then look at the [application lifecycle, especially the route event](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Website_Operation/Events__amp__Application_s_Life_Cycle.html). I believe that's a good point to add a listener that would dispatch the old application. You can find numbers of Listeners in the [Zend MVC code](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/tree/master/src) to base your code on (look at the middleware one for instance).

Comment: hi and thanks - i was able to make some progress to where I created a middleware interceptor (by following https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mvc/middleware/) but I am not sure how to use the `MiddlewareListener`.  Would you be able to suggest how or where to wire it into ZF application?

Comment: also even though I set up my ZF app in the same directory as my main application, I may do better by using a new subfolder, and run zf2 in that subfolder via apache virtual hosts somehow.  That way legacy and zf apps won't directly interfere with each other.  The way I have it now, I'm uncertain if/how I can use Zend to filter all the various many HTTP request/responces of the legacy app through the Middleware application (aka, if I have to define my own mini-HTTP engine inside Middleware, it's likely simpler to just maintain the legacy app as is, and abandon Middleware approach)

Comment: Could you update your post with a simplified example of `index.php` as you have in your legacy projet? Are all the request going through the index? If yes, you can do a pre-dispatch there rather than in a middleware.
The other solution (having two separate projects) can be done, but in order to help you I'll need to know whether you use Nginx, Apache or something else.

Comment: in legacy app not everything goes through the `index.php`.  It goes through whatever the file that URL contains.  i.e. `http://.../my_legacy_module2.php` will call a file on the system that's called `my_legacy_module2.php` and I am using apache

Comment: So basically: if you go with all in one single project, you basically just need to have your ZF project in a subdirectory. Say your apache DOCUMENT_ROOT is /var/www/public, set your project in /var/www, legacy being in /var/www/public, and your ZF3 public folder being /var/www/public/newproject. You'd need to change the paths to go one directory above in index.php (at least for composer autoload and the chdir).
The other solution is indeed two projects, and an Alias in the apache VHost

Comment: the solution that is two projects that you mention in the last sentence, which one do you mean?  I lost you there.  in my mind, if I set up ZF3 in a subdirectory, I will have two "projects" in a way - one the legacy app and two - the ZF3 app when I call that one subdirectory.

Comment: So basically, think of projects in this case as git/svn repository for this answer.
If you go down the road of a subfolder, you would mix new and old code in a single codebase.
If you go with an alias, the alias gets its own DOCUMENT_ROOT. Therefore you can have two separated codebase, on two repositories, and deploy each in their own doc root.

Comment: I'm going with a single repository way and I installed ZF3 first into a separate subfolder, then merged it with main legacy app.  it seems to work.  So I went with an approach other than `Alias`, rewrite, or middleware.  To note, `rewrite` is active for the ZF3 installation (naturally) but not for the main legacy app.  Also not sure if it will matter now but I've updated question with my legacy routing solution.  I will probably rewrite it in ZF3 eventually..... maybe (it's a lot of work!!)